# Separation of the name by the surname and initials

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

There is a list of names and initials, which are separated by a comma and stored in a variable called `$author`

> Shevchuk T.I., Piskun R.P., Vasenko T.B.

It is necessary to separate the initials and surnames separately into variables.

**Example of Names:**

> Belemets N.I. / N.I. Belemets / N. I. Belemets / Belemets N. I. / Belemets N. / N. Belemets / Nu. Belemets / Belemets Nu.

**Now I try to do this as follows:**

```
$str_arr1= explode(", ", $author);
$initials= preg_split('([A-Z]\.[A-Z]\.|[A-Z]\.\s+[A-Z]\.|[A-Z][a-z]\.)', $str_arr1);
$surnames= preg_split('\w{3,15}', $str_arr1);
```

**Example of print_r ($str_arr1):**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Gunas I. V.
    [1] => Babych L. V.
    [2] => Cherkasov E. V.
)
```

But `$initials` and `$surnames` do not output anything. What could be the problem? CMS MODX.

Thanks in advance!

**UPD:**

Now code looks like this:

```
$str_arr= explode(", ", $author);
foreach($str_arr as $value){
    $preinitial= preg_split('/([A-Z]\.[A-Z]\.|[A-Z]\.\s+[A-Z]\.|[A-Z][a-z]\.\s+[A-Z]\.|[A-Z][a-z]\.)/', $value, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    $presurname= preg_split('/\w{3,15}/', $value, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    $initial = implode("", $preinitial);
    $surname = implode("", $presurname);
    echo '<given_name>'.$surname.'</given_name>';
    echo '<surname>'.$initial.'</surname>';
    echo "\r\n";
}
```

Comment: There is a trailing space in your `$str_arr1` assignment. Does your Comma separated list use `", "` or `","`

Comment: There is no mistake, I remove the extra space after comma in that way.

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: Expected: $surnames = Gunas, $initials = I. V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues with your implementation. `preg_split` doesn't take arrays, and requires delimiters. You also should use the `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` so you don't get back empty values. Your variable names also are inverted, the `split` removes what is matched so `$initials` is really the surname, and `$surnames` are really the initials.

```
$author = 'Shevchuk T.I., Piskun R.P., Vasenko T.B.';
$str_arr1= explode(", ", $author);
foreach($str_arr1 as $str_arr) {
    $initials= preg_split('/([A-Z]\.[A-Z]\.|[A-Z]\.\s+[A-Z]\.|[A-Z][a-z]\.)/', $str_arr, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    $surnames= preg_split('/\w{3,15}/', $str_arr, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    print_r($initials);
    print_r($surnames);
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/1sgmX

I'd recommend this library which I've used successfully to parse full references, https://github.com/knmnyn/ParsCit. You can probably pull out the logic to just parse the authors.

The `surname` check with `3,15` also won't work in all cases. For example https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/29052443, `Hong Yu` won't be matched because the surname is only 2 characters.

Comment: Alost there, the code began to work, but for some reason, there is a space before the initials and after the surname <given_name> H. A.</given_name><surname>Oksak </surname>
<given_name> A.L.</given_name><surname>Borkunov </surname>. I use implode co convert array to string like $initial = implode("", $preinitial);. How can I remove whitespaces?

Comment: You could use trim on the assignment, or add `\h*` to both so whitespaces also are split. Can you show how you are using this?

Comment: Give the regexs some whitespaces as well and should work as expected. https://3v4l.org/hjQHC As is the whitespace that were with the name were left behind. Alternatively you can just use `trim` https://3v4l.org/qZVdq (maybe easier for future developers to read?).